# Right way to create criteria for a spefic one-to-many relation with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have this model;

```
@Entity
class Product{
    long id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<ProductFieldValue> fieldValues;
}

@Entity
class ProductFieldValue{
    long id;
    String value;

    @ManyToOne
    Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    ProductField field;
}


@Entity
class ProductField{
    long id;
    @Column(unique=true)
    String name;
}
```

I'm trying to build a query where I can achieve these statements;

A product that has multiple field values with requested fields, such as;

**(product.fieldValues.value = 'val1' && product.fieldValues.field.name = 'field1') && (product.fieldValues.value = 'val2' && product.fieldValues.field.name = 'field2')**

I've tried to JOIN same association twice with Hibernate but appereantly that throws an exception.

What would be the best way to achive this using Criteria or HQL queries ?

Comment: I assume your model here is somewhat simplified but is `ProductField.name` guaranteed to be unique? If not I think you need to join properly using unique keys, that is PK/FK.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I forgot to mention. ProductField.name is unique